# How do you make a usb device thats just an accelerometer

Tags: usb, accelerometer, usb-device, usb-host, usb-hub

So I'm trying to do this with as few components as possible. Also, If possible I would like to skip the microcontroller all together. So how would it be done with a triple axis accelerometer? Any chance you could point me in the right direction and tell me what I would need to start with/learn and where I would need to go there

Comment: More info needed. Which accelerometer are you looking at - what sort of interface (digital or analogue)? Unless your accelerometer has USB capability, you will need something to go in between. But without knowing more about what you are using it is hard to give a definitive answer.

Comment: digital and I am capable of using the one I have with an Arduino already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an MPU6050 connected to a FTDI ft201x usb to serial I2C bridge.

Comment: But that uses a microchip. Is there no way to do it without? Also as a beginner who only has experience with arduinos, could you tell me what I would need to learn?

Comment: @That_One_Dude If all you want is to plug an accelerometer into your computer then just buy a premade one. If you want to build one then at the bare minimum you need an acelerometer and a chip to bridge to USB to make it work.

Comment: I would like to learn how to make one from scratch. How would FTDI201x work? As in how would I program it to communicate over usb?

Comment: @That_One_Dude That's the beauty of it, the chip is preprogrammed for you to communicate USB.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parallel port (I don't think a USB parallel port will work), then you could potentially wire your accelerometer to the pins of the parallel port, then get your computer to bring the individual pins up & down, and read the pins, to communicate with it. You will need to work out the exact protocol to talk to your part - there should be a datasheet for it.

Make sure you check the voltage on your parallel port, and the data sheet for your part, to make sure it can handle the voltages.

Comment: ok thank you. Unfortunately I don't have a parallel port. I guess I'll just have to do it with a microcontroller.